# init() method in tapestry

Tags: java, tapestry

Is there something like `init()` method for a `tapestry` page 
I mean a method that will be executed in the `.java` before the `.tml` is loaded

I am asking this because I need to set some attribute in the session

```
 request.getSession(true).setAttribute("someatt", someatt);
```

before the .tml is loaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! If you create a setupRender() method in your page/component class (or annotate a method with @SetupRender), Tapestry will call that method before rendering the template. The setupRender method is a good place to put initialization code of the sort you want. See http://tapestry.apache.org/component-rendering.html

Answer (score -4):

No. Please [read the documentation](https://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/tapestry5/services/Request.html) before posting. In addition, it would take about 10 minutes tops to test the code and check if it works.

Anyways, this requires you to create an instance (I'm assuming this is the object `request`) of one of the classes that implement the interface. Most things in java don't have an init() method unless they are super complex/relate to drawing. Usually, the stuff in the constructor will take care of the initializing.

Comment: see the answer of @Bob Harner and you will understand why they down voted you.